# There are many icons in top bar of my Kali linux box. Could you please reconize the attched image is related to which process?

Tags: linux

[image: This icon belong to which process in kali linux?]

There are many icons in top bar of my Kali linux box. Could you please reconize the attched image is related to which process?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the icon and click properties at it will show you the command that is executed when you open that launcher.

Hope this helps.

--lillypad